# How to get Insertions and Deletions for NSTableView row animations

Tags: objective-c, macos, animation, nstableview

I'm looking for an API call that provides the `NSMutableIndexSet` of rows to remove and insert for animating rows in an `NSTableView`. Ideally, I should pass an old and new array, to get the resulting remove and insert indices, and I don't see anything like that in `NSTableView` or related protocols.

I'd like to implement animations between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, like so:

```
[_tableView removeRowsAtIndexes:rowsToRemove withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideUp];
[_tableView insertRowsAtIndexes:rowsToInsert withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideDown];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a class for this, with two properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexSet *rowsToRemove;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexSet *rowsToInsert;
```

The initialization takes two arrays (old and new), which I use to get the indices for rows to insert and rows to remove:

```
- (instancetype) initWithOldArray:(NSArray *)oldArray newArray:(NSArray *)newArray
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        //Get a list of deletion indices
        NSMutableIndexSet *rowsToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
        NSUInteger numOldItems = oldArray.count;
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numOldItems; i++) {
            id item = oldArray[i];
            if (![newArray containsObject:item]) {
                [rowsToRemove addIndex:i];
            }
        }

        //Get a list of insertion indices
        NSMutableIndexSet *rowsToInsert = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
        NSUInteger numNewItems = newArray.count;
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numNewItems; i++) {
            id item = newArray[i];
            if (![oldArray containsObject:item]) {
                [rowsToInsert addIndex:i];
            }
        }

        self.rowsToRemove = rowsToRemove;
        self.rowsToInsert = rowsToInsert;
    }

    return self;
}
```